# Integrate a prometheus gauge into a counter using rules?

Tags: prometheus, metrics

I have a system that (unfortunately) only reports a positive-only gauge, when it really should report a counter. Many of my graphs integrate over the 15s (or whatever interval) readings of the past day or week to approximate, which is wasteful, sometimes prohibitively so for larger windows.

Is there a way to write a rule that records that counter by summing up samples from the reported gauge? One could picture this an a sum_over_time with an infinite window (and hence no need to actually keep track of the start of the window).

Domain: electricity production / consumption to/from grid. My system only reports power (W), but does not have an energy (Wh) counter. And no, I cannot change this easily.

Question 62063661 appears to indicate that this is not possible.

Comment: I wouldn't use "sum over time" but rather "average over time" wich will give you the average W taking into account all data points over a time range. Then a recording rule with careful interval could do the job. The whole setup looks fragile and I don't know what you can do if you can't trust the measure.

Comment: Thx - I wanted to use sum_over_time in order to "re-create" the energy counter that would only ever increase (which is what I would really want from the underlying system, but do not get).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.